# Getting the first day of week

Tags: mysql, date-format

In continuation of my previous question:
[Get week/month data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29848/get-week-month-data)

I have a MySQL table with `day` column of type `DATE` and `position` column of type `INT`.

I need to fetch average position for every week in consideration. (A week is in consideration if there is a row with `day` value belonging to this week.)

The fetched data should be an array of two columns:

- date
- position

Here "date" is the first day (Sunday) of the week and "position" is the average position for this week.

The trouble is how to get the first day for a week.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in comments of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(day, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(day)) DAY) AS day, AVG(position) AS position FROM table
```

Comment: This gives the last day of the week. To get the first day of the week you need to do `DATE(day - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(day) - 1) DAY)`. If you want the first monday, subtract 2 instead of 1.